# Makefile for compiling Markdown files to a single PDF

Tags: makefile

I am trying to use a Makefile for compiling a PDF when any of a number of Markdown files change:

```
# Compile report

source := draft
output := dist
sources := $(wildcard $(source)/*.md)
objects := $(patsubst %.md,%.pdf,$(subst$(source),$(output),$(sources)))
all: $(objects)

report-print.md: $(source)/%.md
    cat draft/*.md | pandoc \
        --variable geometry:a4paper \
        --number-sections \ 
        --toc \
        --f markdown \
        -s \
        -o dist/report-print.pdf \ 

.PHONY : clean

clean:
    rm -f $(output)/*.pdf
```

I get an error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `dist/01-title.pdf', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

The file `draft/01-title.md` is one of of the source files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have a rule for creating one `.pdf` file from one `.md` file.  Which is fine, because that's not what you want to do.  You want to create a single `pdf` file from *all* the `.md` files (as I understand it).  So, ditch all the `objects` stuff; you don't need to create all those individual `pdf` files.

There are a number of other minor problems: you aren't creating the same filename as your target (`report-print.md` vs. `$(output)/report-print.pdf`), you should use automatic variables, etc.)

Your makefile will simply be:

```
source := draft
output := dist
sources := $(wildcard $(source)/*.md)

all: $(output)/report-print.pdf

$(output)/report-print.pdf: $(sources)
        cat $^ | pandoc \
            --variable geometry:a4paper \
            --number-sections \
            --toc \
            --f markdown \
            -s \
            -o $@

.PHONY : clean

clean:
        rm -f $(output)/*.pdf
```

Comment: That produces an error: `
cat draft/01-title.md draft/02-abstract.md draft/03-introduction.md draft/04-methods.md draft/05-results.md draft/06-discussion.md draft/07-acknowledgments.md draft/08-litterature-cited.md | pandoc \
  --variable geometry:a4paper \
  --number-sections \ 
pandoc:  : openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
make: *** [dist/report-print.pdf] Error 1`

Comment: I can't really read that error message properly in an unformatted comment.  Are you sure that the arguments after "--number-sections" are missing?  No --toc, etc.?  If so that probably means you have extraneous whitespace after the backslash on the --number-sections line.  Remember that for an escaped newline the backslash must be the _last_ character on the line; if there are spaces after it then the backslash is quoting the spaces, not the newline.

Comment: @MasScientist Yes, it was a whitespace character. It works now, thanks!